# Spindle-shaped distribution like a sea seal?

Tags: data-visualization, probability, distributions

What probability distribution’s diagram is similar to the body shape of a Caspian Sea Seal? I mean a distribution which is rounded in the middle, and tapered at the both ends. Different distribution parameters make it change its shape (different skewness & kurtosis).

Comment: This looks a lot like homework to me.

Comment: No Dan, not a homework :)

Answer (score 3):

[Johnson SU (or SB)](https://www.ntrand.com/johnson-su-distribution/) distribution is your sea seal. You can play with gamma and delta parameters to make it skewed and fatter tailed. It's a transformation of a normal variable, very easy to deal with.

[image]